# Running web-server from inside chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm very much new to chrome app development, for my application I need to run a web-server which will start as my app launch and will be close with closing of my app. I like to use web-server-for-chrome plugin as my web-server but is there any way to start and stop a server from inside chrome app?

Comment: So.. why do you need a **web server** for chrome applications which are simple javascript/css/html? This sounds like absolute insanity to me, unless something really, really odd happened in the last few months in the world of development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you would need to use [`chrome.sockets.tcpServer api`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer), it allows you to create server applications using TCP connections.

And for examples, take a look at [chrome-app-samples-webserver](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webserver).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [web-server-chrome](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome) for this.

As you mention, it's important to stop the web server so that the app's background or event page can suspend. You could create an chrome.app.window.onClosed handler and check if there are no more windows, and then call .stop() on the WebApplication object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Haibara for putting me in the right direction. I have actually made a small library from your advice which answers the original question.

https://github.com/markwylde/https-server

```
const https = new ServerHttps()

https.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello there')
})

https.listen(9999)
```

It exposes an express like api, which you can run as an extension.

A better demo can be seen here:
https://github.com/markwylde/https-server-demo